# Multi-Condition Probability

Tags: probability

I want to guess whether a person has a health condition (we'll say sleep apnea for simplicity's sake). I know a person has Gene A and 99% of people with this gene have sleep apnea. I also know that this person has Gene B and only 49% of people with Gene B have sleep apnea.

How do I calculate the probability that this person has sleep apnea, assuming this is the only information I have?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't, without more data.

Comment: What other data do you need?

Comment: Well, basically data concerning the incidence of the condition in people with both genes.  A priori there is no mathematical way to guess anything regarding the interaction of the two genes.